# Click to add hidden input; How can I write a function which can add infinite new inputs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code. When click "add more", it displays a hidden input textarea. How to put it
in a function, then I can click to add more indefinitely? I tried, but didn't succeed. Thanks!

```js
function HideContent(d) {
document.getElementById('cng').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('cng').innerHTML='Click to show.';
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
}
function ShowContent(d, s) {
document.getElementById(s).style.display = "none";
document.getElementById(d).style.display = "list-item";
}
function ReverseDisplay(d) {
if(document.getElementById(d).style.display == "none") { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; }
else { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="textarea" name="user3">
<a href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename1', 'cng1')" backgorund="orange">
<div id="cng1" style="display">Click to add more.</div>
</a>

<div id="uniquename1" style="display:none;">
<input type="textarea" name="user1">
<a href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename2', 'cng2')">
<div id="cng2" style="display">Click to add more</div>
</a>
</div>

<div id="uniquename2" style="display:none;">
<input type="textarea" name="user2">
<a href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename3', 'cng3')">
<div id="cng3" style="display">Click to add more</div>
</a>
</div>

<br><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than coding each input from the start, you should dynamically create them with the JS function using `createElement`:

```js
var inputNumber = 0,
    
  inputHolder = document.getElementById("inputHolder"),
    
  addInput = function() {
    // Creates new input
    var myNewBox = document.createElement("input");

    // Gives the unique name to the input
    myNewBox.setAttribute("name", "cng" + inputNumber);

    // Adds one so the next input will get a new name
    inputNumber++;

    // Adds the new box to the input holder, plus a br tag
    inputHolder.appendChild(myNewBox);
    inputHolder.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
  };

// Adds the initial input box
addInput();
```

```html
<form>

  <div id="inputHolder"></div>

  <br/>

  <a href="javascript:addInput()">Add another?</a>

  <br/>

  <br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I need. But I put your codes together, and run it. It didn't work for me. Please see my post below.

Comment: It runs for me in the code snippet above, and it doesn't require any jQuery. In your repost below, did you separate the JS and HTML, or just paste it all in the same section?

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work for me. My code is exactly like my post below. It's in one file. I separated the JS with the <script> tag. I just copied your JS part and HTML part, and put them in one file. Why doesn't it work for me? Please help! Thanks!!

Comment: I don't know for sure why. Are you declaring the JavaScript correctly? Is there any error appearing in the console when you attempt to use it?